# How to get sessionId from server if the login is authenticated in android?

Tags: android, validation

I'm validating the form data as the response I'm getting total feed of that URL but i `need only session Id` from that how can i do this.can any body help regarding this..

Now as below shown way i'm getting response from server how can i get required one from that..

```
 <data>
<limit>
<uname>android</uname>
<pwd>androiddeveloper</pwd>
<sessionid>abcdef56789ghijkl90a<sessionid/>
</limit>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974591/parsing-a-xml-httpresponse) and is worked fine for me thanks to that guy who solved it.

```
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
    String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
    inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
    Document doc = db.parse(inStream);  

    String playcount = "empty";
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("playcount");
    for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             org.w3c.dom.Element nameElement = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nl.item(i);
             playcount = nameElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire query for that. If the user is authenticated then get user's userId and store in some ***static*** variable.
This might you need i think.

Comment: as the response i'm getting the above data how can retrieve required data suppose i need uname from the above xml how can i retrieve that.